# Как избавиться от потери точности float в opengl?

Tags: opengl, float

При попытке смоделировать 3D планету с различными уровнями детализации получаю следующее:

сфера радиусом 6700 единиц, естественно, разделена по quadTree, хотя не суть важно. Таким образом, поверхность земли находится примерно на расстоянии 6700 от центра СК, и чем ближе камера приближена к поверхности, тем больше "трясутся" вершины, что вызвано потерей точности при построении матрицы MVP, так как позиция камеры и объектов основаны на больших значениях.

Чтобы избежать этого, пробовал перед генерацией Model и View матриц делать предварительный offset позиций на позицию камеры. То есть View камеры будет как будто в (0,0,0), а позиция других мешей в (позиция меша.xyz - позиция камеры.xyz), но в таком случае при каждом кадре приходится перегенерировать Model матрицы(да и лишние операции усложняют структуру) для каждого меша, а это слишком затратно при их большом количестве.
Есть ли какие-либо хаки, чтобы чтобы устранить проблему, и не прибегать к таким затратным операциям на каждый кадр?

Comment: Вы решили свою пооблему? если нет ответьте, возможно я смогу Вам помочь.

Answer (score 2):

Я не знаю как именно у вас строится некая матрица, но возможно что её нормировка после построения (или нормировка данных до построения) поможет. Если матрица содержит большие близкие значения то при вычислении скалярных произведений будет потеря точности, если значения в матрице не велики значит точность потерялась где-то при её построении (возможно что так-же из-за ненормированных исходных данных).
Смещение позиции о котором вы писали это только часть нормировки, еще требуется изменить масштаб умножением на подходящий нормирующий скаляр.

Comment: какой скаляр брать? Кажется, пробовал что-то подобное с масштабированием, но проблема остается, так как при любом масштабировании соотношение расстояний от центра СК к камере и объекту одинаковое, то есть трясение вершин происходит как при камере в (123456789,0,0) и вершинах относительно (123456788,0,0), так (12.3456789,0,0) и (12.3456788,0,0) соответственно

Comment: обычно скаляр выбирается как среднее м/у всеми точками умножить на sqrt(2), если подходящий скаляр не находится (или не существует) тогда остается одно из двух, либо сам алгоритм построения матрицы является не очень устойчивым (например прямой метод наименьших квадратов через псевдоинверсию вместо необходимого сингулярного разложения), либо данные таковы что точности float для них маловато, сама матрица то тоже на float-ах считается? мб на double перевести а сами данные оставить во float-ах?

Comment: а вообще неплохо было бы увидеть хотя-бы порядок значений в матрице, просто дрожание таки означает что потери происходят именно в момент непосредственного применения матрицы (например при умножении / делении на большие величины), если конечно все верно считается

Comment: вот пример https://jsfiddle.net/0k7jsg0t/9/

Comment: именно необходимо то(показано за счет ползунка OFFSET), чтобы камера была на минимальной дистанции к объекту, который вместе с ней отдален из центра СК,например камера и ландшафт расположены на расстоянии 6700 единиц(6 700 000 метров) от центра СК, а расстояние между камерой и поверхностью ландшафта и другими объектами может быть равна 0.001 (1 метр), и тогда получаю дрожание

Comment: тем более, если правильно я понял из док-ов, то в ogl es и webgl нельзя передать матрицу в glsl с двойной точностью, хотя сами float в JS по сути с двойной точностью, но все равно на каком то шаге теряется точностью при больших значениях

Comment: идея со скаляром не работает, так как тогда нужно делать scale всей геометрии, и в итоге получается то же самое